# Help understanding limit in Spivak Calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

So Im confused by a limit. The limit as h approaches zero of

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {\sqrt{x + h} - \sqrt x}{h}$$

The answer I came to was $ \dfrac 1 {2 \sqrt  x}$. But from what I look up the limit does not exist because "there are no values to the left of zero in the domain of the function." I am not sure why this makes a difference when it comes to this limit. Because $\sqrt{x}$ has a limit and yet the domain also has no values to the left of zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the author is enforcing that to have the limit at a point, it must have a limit on both sides, even for boundary points .

That said, the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0-h)-f(0)}{-h}$ does not exist: there is no unique number which is a limit of these expressions because the expression is undefined for all positive $h$.  So technically one could say it lacks a limit on the left at $0$, half of the requirement for having a limit at $0$.

But for all $x>0$, the limit *does* exist, on both sides, and is what you said it is.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense thanks.

Comment: Ok so I have one more question related to this. Later on one of the problems is prove that if a limit exists then the left and right limits exist and are equal. Am I correct in saying this is not possible if we use the definition of a limit involving all x in the domain of f? As opposed to the definition given of for all x.

Comment: @RyanSchardine Hm, well I guess I’m hampered by not knowing how he defined “limit exists”.  I thought he was defining as the exercise indicates, but apparently this is not so.

Comment: He defines it "for all epsilon greater than zero there is some delta such that for all x if 0 is less than /x-a/ is less than delta then /f(x)-l/ is less than epsilon."